# I want the text to randomize every time I press enter and "restart" the program

Tags: processing

I am working on a game revolving around a restart mechanic, however, I want it to randomly generate a different word each time I restart the program, but I'm having a difficult enough time as it is getting it to randomize when clicking a different key. What is the issue here?

I have tried randomizing it in different locations, including in setup(); however, that doesn't work either. this is what I have so far-

```java
    float bx=1500/2;
    float by=900/2;
    float b=0;
    
    
    float ix=20;
    float iy=20;
    
    String [] sus={"strange","interesting","odd", "unsusual","abnormal","different","irregular","deviant","funny"};
       
    
    
    boolean restart;
    
    
    int c1=0;
    
    int rest=0;
        
    
    
    void setup(){
      size(1500,900);
      
      println(c1);
      
      
      
      
      if( restart == true){
        println(c1);
      }
       
    }
    
    void draw(){
      background(240,240,250);
      
      
      
      rect(bx,by,20,20);
      rect(ix,iy,40,40);
      
        // interactivity
    
        
    
    
      // player movement
      if( keyPressed == true){
        b=5;
        
        if( key == 'w'|| key== 'W'){
            by=by-b;
          }
        }
      if( key == 'a'|| key== 'A'){
          bx=bx-b;
        }
        if( key == 's'|| key== 'S'){
          by=by+b;
        }
         if( key == 'd'|| key== 'D'){
          bx=bx+b;
        } 
        
        if( key == CODED){
          if(keyCode == UP){
            by=by-b;
          }
        }
        if( key == CODED){
          if(keyCode == LEFT){
            bx=bx-b;
          }
        }
        if( key == CODED){
          if(keyCode == RIGHT){
            bx=bx+b;
          }
        }
        if( key == CODED){
          if(keyCode == DOWN){
            by=by+b;
          }
        } 
        
        //braking mechanisim
      if( keyPressed == false){
        b=0; 
      }
      
      //interactivity
       if( key == ' '){
         if(dist( bx, by, ix, iy) < 50){
           
          textSize(20);
          text(sus[c1], 100,100,width/2,height/2); 
        }
         fill(20,172,218);
         
          
       }
      if( key == CODED){
        if( key == ENTER){
          rest++;
        }
      }
      
      
      
     
    }
    
    void keyReleased(){
      
      if(key == CODED){
        if(key == ENTER){ 
          for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            c1=int(random(0,sus.length-1));
          }
        }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue and behavior you're seeing? It's unclear to me but I can see a few issues in your code. For one, you're generating your random number 3 times in a for loop but overwriting the result each time. Effectively making it 1 random selection since only the last one should matter.

Comment: In your `keyReleased()` when `key == CODED` the second if-statement will never be true, as key is already CODED. So c1 will never be other then it's initial value. And therefor the string "strange" will be printed always.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reseed the RNG if you want different results on each execution. Standard method is to use the current time as the random seed.

I see this code is tagged as "processing", looking at [the docs](https://processing.org/reference/randomSeed_.html), the command you're looking for should be `randomSeed(0);` replace 0 with the [current timestamp](https://processing.org/reference#input-time-date)

Comment: although those are true, I'm not sure this is OP's issue. I think not.